# Dynamic insert into variable table statement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a variable table:

```
DECLARE @A_Table TABLE(ID INT, att1 VARCHAR(100), att2 nvarchar(200))
```

I want to make dynamic sql, so I insert into this table some data (all inside a loop):

```
WHILE (@i <= 100) BEGIN         
  SELECT @other_att  = NAME  FROM @other_Table where ID =  @i;
  SET @sql = 'INSERT ' + @A_Table+ '(ID,att1,att2) SELECT '+CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)+' , '''+ @other_att+''', SUM('+ @other_att') FROM '+ @EVEN_OTHER_Table;
EXEC (@sql);

END
```

sql every time would look like:

```
INSERT INTO @A_Table SELECT 1 , 'subject', SUM(subject)
INSERT INTO @A_Table SELECT 2 , 'age', SUM(age)
INSERT INTO @A_Table SELECT 3 , 'sex', SUM(sex)....
```

AND after executing this :
SO I will get:

```
@A_Table:
id    att1   att2
1   subject   4.3
2   age       4.5
3   sex       4.1
```

but I get an error:

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
Must declare the scalar variable "@A_Table".
```

SO what is it the syntax to insert dynamically into  a variable table?

Ok I have understood it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a table variable, not a variable that contains the table name.

So you would need the following.

```
WHILE (@i <= 100) BEGIN         
  SELECT @other_att  = NAME  FROM @other_Table where ID =  @i;
  SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO @A_Table (ID,att1,att2) SELECT '+CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)+' , '''+ @other_att+''', SUM('+ @other_att') FROM @EVEN_OTHER_Table';
EXEC (@sql);

END
```

You would also need to declare the table variable as a statement inside the `@sql` variable, and execute your declare table and inserts together, or use a local/global temporary table.

With a local temporary table (stored in the tempdb) you could do something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE #testtbl (ID INT);
EXEC ('INSERT INTO #testtbl VALUES (1)');
SELECT * FROM #testtbl
DROP TABLE #testtbl
```

Some good info about temporary tables in BOL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx - quite far down the page

And the `table` type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx

Comment: It keeps saying that `@A_Table` is not declared, but its is...       ` Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the table variable "@A_Table".`

Comment: How is @sql declared, Do you recommend using a temporal table?

Comment: that's because @A_Table is not in the same scope, it depends what you are trying to achieve but you could add the statements to declare your variable and inserts inside @sql and then execute (@sql), but you may want a temporary table instead. Which will allow it to be declared in a different scope http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables

Answer (score 12):

You could use the `INSERT ... EXEC` syntax to insert the data returned by the dynamic SELECT. Of course, you would then need to remove the `INSERT` part from the dynamic statement.

```
WHILE (@i <= 100) BEGIN         
  SELECT @other_att  = NAME  FROM @other_Table where ID =  @i;
  SET @sql = 'SELECT '+CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)+' , ''' + @other_att+''', SUM('+ @other_att + ') FROM '+ @EVEN_OTHER_Table;
  INSERT INTO @A_Table (ID,att1,att2)
    EXEC (@sql);
END
```

Comment: In this case Is It is more efficient to use `sp_execute`?

Comment: @darkcminor: A quick look through the results of googling for `exec vs sp_executesql` didn't reveal to me any particular advantages of `EXEC()` over `sp_executesql` in what I would call ordinary cases, to which I would include yours as well. I'm sorry, I cannot tell you much about that, but [some](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#EXEC4) people have certainly studied the matter more thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

Your EXEC statement occurs in a different context and is therefore unaware of any variables created in your original context.

Answer (score 0):

To create dynamic insert query it is really a task, I also struggle to find it ,finally I have tried in the following way and it's successfully working. Please find the code below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTodaysData] (@tbl varchar(50),@Days int,
 @MDate varchar(50), @EValue varchar(50), @Speed varchar(50),
@Totalreturn varchar(50),@Closingv varchar(50), @TotalReturnV varchar(50))

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQLQuery varchar(2000)
-- Insert statements for procedure here
set @SQLQuery = 'INSERT INTO '+@tbl+' (ID,MDate,EValue,Speed,TotalReturnRatio,ClosingValue,
TotalReturnValue) VALUES ('+@Days+','''+@MDate+''', '+@EValue+', '+@Speed+',
 '+@Totalreturn+', '+@Closingv+', '+@TotalReturnV+')'

EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)

END
```

Hope this will help you..