# Dynamic sql using table variable -TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My problem is using a table variable in a exec.

```
declare @sort_col nvarchar(1000) = 'itm_id'
declare @sort_dir nvarchar(4) = 'desc'
declare @filters nvarchar(1000) = ' and itm_name like ''%aa%'''

declare @temp table
(
 itm_id int
)

insert into @temp
EXEC('select itm_id from Tblitm where itm_name not like ''%aa%''')

EXEC('select * from (select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY '+@sort_col+' '+@sort_dir+')) row_num, * FROM (select itm_id, itm_name, 
dbo.fnItmsHistory(itm_id) itm_history
         from dbo.Tblitm as itm
         left outer join '+@temp+' as temp on itm.itm_id = temp.itm_id
         where itm_id=itm_id and temp.itm_id = null '+@filters+') as x) as tmp')
```

It says Must declare the scalar variable "@temp" when the temp table is declared i tried using original temp table and it worked, but i had problems when trying to update my entity model.So is there any solution for this problem?

Note:
I must use exec because in filters i store string for the where clause.

Comment: Use #temp instead of @temp and just reference #temp directly in the EXEC() instead of treating it like a variable name.

Comment: See [Dynamic insert into variable table statement SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196434/dynamic-insert-into-variable-table-statement-sql-server)

Comment: @AaronBertrand i made the query functional like that, but i had problems when updating my entity model so i am afraid i cant use that fix.

Comment: I have the exact problem when using temp table.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593473/ef-cant-infer-return-schema-from-stored-procedure-selecting-from-a-temp-table

Comment: Wow, EF is pretty annoyingly intrusive, eh? In theory, it should be able to determine the output of the stored procedure without caring what comes before the first select. Out of curiosity, what happens if you encrypt the stored procedure?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes that's what i thought so, and sorry i cant do the encryption i am still a sql rookie and i haven't encrypted any stored procedure yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solution i had to use a temp table and then on the start of my stored procedure i used the if condition from the [EF can't infer return schema from Stored Procedure selecting from a #temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593473/ef-cant-infer-return-schema-from-stored-procedure-selecting-from-a-temp-table) anwser.

It's the best solution for this scenario i think.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the table variable inside the dynamic statement.

```
EXEC('
declare @temp table
(
 itm_id int
)
insert into @temp
select itm_id from Tblitm where itm_name not like ''%aa%''
select * from (select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY '+@sort_col+' '+@sort_dir+')) row_num, * FROM (select itm_id, itm_name, 
dbo.fnItmsHistory(itm_id) itm_history
         from dbo.Tblitm as itm
         left outer join @temp as temp on itm.itm_id = temp.itm_id
         where itm_id=itm_id and temp.itm_id = null '+@filters+') as x) as tmp')
```

Comment: This is a solution that works, but i cant use this as a solution it slows the query down significantly.

Comment: @Aleks Why do you need a temp table anyway, why not join with the sub-query `select itm_id from Tblitm where itm_name not like ''%aa%''` directly instead?

Comment: the query i wrote is an example i have a lot more complicated query and when i put it all in exec it takes a lot more time than using a temp table.